# ISBLANK Range? How to check a range for being blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The formula below does:

1. Check to see if the range has two or more "A"s

2.1 If yes true

2.2 If no false

3.11 If yes and BB1 is blank, show "Chronic"

3.12 If yes and BB1 in not blank, show ""

3.21 If no and BB1 is blank, show ""

3.22 If no and BB1 is not blank, show ""

```
=IF(ISBLANK(BB1),IF((COUNTIF(A1:BA1,"A")+COUNTIF(A1:BA1,"a"))>2,"Chronic",""),"")
```

What I would like it to do is:

1. Check to see if the range has two or more "A"s

2.1 If yes true

2.2 If no false

3.11 If yes and BB1:BC1 is blank, show "Chronic"

3.12 If yes and BB1:BC1 in not blank, show ""

3.21 If no and BB1:BC1 is blank, show ""

3.22 If no and BB1:BC1 is not blank, show ""

```
=IF(ISBLANK(BB1:BC1),IF((COUNTIF(A1:BA1,"A")+COUNTIF(A1:BA1,"a"))>2,"Chronic",""),"")
```

However the issue with this is it will ALWAYS show blank. I am assuming I am confusing the formula. Essentially BB1:BC1 is trying to say BB1 AND/OR BC1, not BB1 AND BC1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First COUNTIF() is not case specific.

Second just use another COUNTIF()

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(BB1:BC1,"=")=2,COUNTIF(A1:BA1,"A")>2),"Chronic","")
```

Comment: I am unable to use this formula as it brings back an error and unfortunately I cannot spot where. It says I am missing parenthesis.